# GeoServer Printing Module - Error while Printing

Tags: geoserver, printing

I like to print a map via Leaflet.

I installed GeoServer Print Module (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html) on a Test-GeoServer.

After that I run this URL in a Browser, because I want to test, if printing ist possible, before I start with JavaScript.

```
GEOSERVERURL/pdf/print.pdf?spec=%7B%22units%22%3A%22m%22%2C%22srs%22%3A%22EPSG%3A3857%22%2C%22layout%22%3A%22A4%20portrait%22%2C%22dpi%22%3A300%2C%22outputFormat%22%3A%22pdf%22%2C%22outputFilename%22%3A%22leaflet-map%22%2C%22layers%22%3A%5B%7B%22baseURL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fa.tile.osm.org%2F%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A1%2C%22type%22%3A%22OSM%22%2C%22extension%22%3A%22png%22%2C%22tileSize%22%3A%5B256%2C256%5D%2C%22maxExtent%22%3A%5B-20037508.34%2C-20037508.34%2C20037508.34%2C20037508.34%5D%2C%22resolutions%22%3A%5B156543.03390625%2C78271.516953125%2C39135.7584765625%2C19567.87923828125%2C9783.939619140625%2C4891.9698095703125%2C2445.9849047851562%2C1222.9924523925781%2C611.4962261962891%2C305.74811309814453%2C152.87405654907226%2C76.43702827453613%2C38.218514137268066%2C19.109257068634033%2C9.554628534317017%2C4.777314267158508%2C2.388657133579254%2C1.194328566789627%2C0.5971642833948135%5D%2C%22singleTile%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22Vector%22%2C%22styles%22%3A%7B%221%22%3A%7B%22externalGraphic%22%3A%22file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fastrid%2Fgit%2Fleaflet%2FLeaflet.print%2Fexamples%2Fmarker-icon.png%22%2C%22graphicWidth%22%3A6%2C%22graphicHeight%22%3A9.84%2C%22graphicXOffset%22%3A-2.88%2C%22graphicYOffset%22%3A-9.84%7D%7D%2C%22styleProperty%22%3A%22_leaflet_style%22%2C%22geoJson%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22FeatureCollection%22%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22Feature%22%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%22_leaflet_style%22%3A1%7D%2C%22geometry%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22Point%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B19454491.990670364%2C-4418590.454805996%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22pages%22%3A%5B%7B%22center%22%3A%5B19454491.990670364%2C-4418590.454805996%5D%2C%22scale%22%3A25000%2C%22rotation%22%3A0%7D%5D%2C%22mapTitle%22%3A%22Print%20Test%22%2C%22comment%22%3A%22Testing%20Leaflet%20printing%22%7D
```

But I only get a timeout Error.
The `Error Stack` that I can see on the GeoServer, the `config.yaml` and the print `info.json` I attached here.

Why is it not possible to print this map?

Error

```
    2019-11-23 11:47:10.024:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @30946ms
2019-11-23 11:49:38.133:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:qtp792791759-20: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
trac.mapfish.org
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:136)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.print.PrintTranscoder.print(PrintTranscoder.java:307)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ImageBlock$SvgDrawer.renderImpl(ImageBlock.java:140)
        at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.render(ChunkDrawer.java:55)
        at org.mapfish.print.ChunkDrawer.tableLayout(ChunkDrawer.java:49)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:786)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1765)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPRow.writeCells(PdfPRow.java:549)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:764)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:889)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1774)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:882)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:877)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:866)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2602)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:727)
        at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:278)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page$1.add(Page.java:76)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ImageBlock.drawSVG(ImageBlock.java:91)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ImageBlock.render(ImageBlock.java:64)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:52)
        at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:31)
        at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
        at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:175)
        at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:370)
        at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createAndGetPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:166)
        at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doGet(MapPrinterServlet.java:97)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: trac.mapfish.org
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1950)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1945)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1514)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURLData.openStreamInternal(ParsedURLData.java:554)
        at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURLData.openStream(ParsedURLData.java:476)
        at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURL.openStream(ParsedURL.java:440)
        at org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(SAXSVGDocumentFactory.java:158)
        at org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(SAXSVGDocumentFactory.java:283)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:129)
        ... 129 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: trac.mapfish.org
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3057)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:512)
        at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURLData.openStreamInternal(ParsedURLData.java:548)
        ... 134 more
ERROR: null
Enclosed Exception:
null
Enclosed Exception:
trac.mapfish.org
23 Nov 11:54:41 WARN [print.MapPrinter] - [Overtime Print] {"layout":"A4 portrait","mapTitle":"Print Test","outputFilename":"leaflet-map","pages":[{"center":[1.9454491990670364E7,-4418590.454805996],"rotation":0,"scale":25000}],"srs":"EPSG:3857","layers":[{"baseURL":"http://a.tile.osm.org/","extension":"png","singleTile":false,"tileSize":[256,256],"resolutions":[156543.03390625,78271.516953125,39135.7584765625,19567.87923828125,9783.939619140625,4891.9698095703125,2445.9849047851562,1222.9924523925781,611.4962261962891,305.74811309814453,152.87405654907226,76.43702827453613,38.218514137268066,19.109257068634033,9.554628534317017,4.777314267158508,2.388657133579254,1.194328566789627,0.5971642833948135],"opacity":1,"type":"OSM","maxExtent":[-2.003750834E7,-2.003750834E7,2.003750834E7,2.003750834E7]},{"styleProperty":"_leaflet_style","geoJson":{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[1.9454491990670364E7,-4418590.454805996],"type":"Point"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"_leaflet_style":1}}],"type":"FeatureCollection"},"styles":{"1":{"graphicYOffset":-9.84,"externalGraphic":"file:///home/astrid/git/leaflet/Leaflet.print/examples/marker-icon.png","graphicHeight":9.84,"graphicWidth":6,"graphicXOffset":-2.88}},"type":"Vector"}],"comment":"Testing Leaflet printing","units":"m","dpi":300,"outputFormat":"pdf"}
23 Nov 11:54:41 WARN [servlet.BaseMapServlet] - Cannot delete file:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-geoserver-_geoserver-any-7876739665322534668.dir\mapfish-print3353911634300635794.pdf.printout
23 Nov 11:54:41 ERROR [servlet.BaseMapServlet] - Error while generating PDF
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:786)
        at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:278)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page$1.add(Page.java:76)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MapBlock.render(MapBlock.java:81)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:73)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
        at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
        at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:31)
        at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
        at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:175)
        at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:370)
        at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createAndGetPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:166)
        at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doGet(MapPrinterServlet.java:97)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
```